# Mongo get users whose id ends in a certain digit

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, find

In mongo, I'm trying to query for users with an id that ends in a certain number.  This number is a parameter that I pass in.

So if I had 4 users [3544,42345,66452,7348], how could i query and just get user 7348 if i was just interested in users whose id ends in 8.

I've looked through here, but can't find exactly what would work for this:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

UPDATE:
doing this is PHP, and the expected values are int's, not strings.  My where clause looks like this:
$where = array('uid'=>'/8$/');

Comment: If you are using a Regular Expression in the Mongo-PHP-Extension, you should use the MongoRegex class.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to find a user whose id end in the digit 8 you would just have to do this:

```
db.users.find( { id : /[8]$/ } );
```

$ matches to the end of the line. just like ^ matches the beginning of the line.
refer to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for further details

For finding last digit of int type data fields you would have to use the $mod operator.

Comment: this worked for columns that were numeric strings.  Wasn't working for columns that were ints.  Is that plausible?

Answer (score 8):

This should do it:

```
db.users.find( { id : { $mod : [ 10 , 8 ] } } )
```